# Errors after upgrading to Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

I've just upgraded and installed Qt 5 from the official website: https://qt-project.org/downloads
Version I chose:

> Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 823 MB)

The problem is nothing's no longer working! When I try to run code that perfectly compiled with Qt 4.8, I have 66 errors.

Here are a few examples:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QLabel'
>   error: forward declaration of 'class QLabel'
>   error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QLineEdit'

Very strange errors.

Here is the Compile Output:

> mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
>   21:10:34: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project SQLWidgetMapper (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
>   When executing step 'Make'

Can anyone could give me a clue?

Comment: Qt4 and 5 are not source compatible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QWidgets` [have been moved into a separate module](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt5-intro.html#widgets-in-qt-5).  You read the docs, right?

Comment: Thanks boy, it works! I just replaced <QtGui> by <QtWidgets> in the include.

Comment: You shouldn't include <QtWidgets/QLabel>, if you properly add the module into your .pro file you can use <QLabel>, also you can add the widgets module only if Qt5 id used and then most of the source code becomes compatible with both Qt4 and Qt5.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.0 installed at the same time?  Check what is in your path environment variable.